# How to compare datetimes from different timezones

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Any way to compare 2 DateTimes from different timezones. I has 1 DateTime that come from server it's UTC+3:00 and DateTime on local machine that is UTC+6:00. How to compare that 2 DateTimes so when DateTime 1(server) will be >= DateTime 2(client) so i can do something.

P.S
Ye, i know how to compare DateTimes, but i don't know how to do that when they are in difference timezones.

Comment: Easiest way is to use UTC times. No timezone hooplah to deal with, then.

Comment: Lots of existing questions on this subject.  Show your research and what you tried already please.  If you haven't done any research, please do so before asking.

Comment: can you include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  There are various different timezone solutions for various different frameworks, and an SSCCE would help

Comment: [MCVE] would be better.

Comment: Convert the times to UTC by calling [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495915(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you can compare them directly.

Comment: Once the two dates are in DateTime object they are already converted to UTC and you an compare without any conversions.  Not timezone settings are required provided you parsed the two strings with a UTC settings.  DateTimes are stored internally in the computer as UTC.  Dates are imported using default Timezone settings of computer but if you import using the timezone setting where the data is collected the conversion is automatically done by the DateTime parse method.

Comment: It's also important to know that the `DateTime` object does not persist any time zone information other than the tri-state `DateTimeKind`.  So the question, as asked, is unanswerable.  You need to provide more details and specific examples.  See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @jdweng that what i do now, i just send packets from serve with "server time" and compare on client init server date and packet server date. But i don't want to do that any more)

Comment: It is the proper way of comparing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have two DateTime objects that represent the same Instant in time but in different time zones.

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddHours(3);

// change kind to unspecified
dt1 = new DateTime(dt1.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
dt2 = new DateTime(dt2.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

// append the offset for each time
var offset1 = new DateTimeOffset(dt1, TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
var offset2 = new DateTimeOffset(dt2, TimeSpan.FromHours(6));

// compare
bool areEqual = offset1.Equals(offset2); // true
```

Although the above works, i highly advise you to take a look at [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/): An alternative Date and Time API for .NET that makes working with Timezones really more explicit and efficient and forces you to make explicit decisions in cases of DST. Also the API introduces more types to deal with different scenarios, in your case you need to work with `ZonedDateTime`